# Beamer. Berkeley. How to move up the right index?

Tags: beamer

How could I move up the right index in Beamer?

[image]

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\makeatletter
\beamer@headheight=1.5\baselineskip

\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{10.2}\selectfont}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\logo{\color{blue!50}\scalebox{2}{unir}}

\frame
{
\begin{center}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{UNIR-Logo.jpg}  
    \end{figure}

\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,1.00}{Universidad Internacional de La Rioja}\\
\vspace{0.32cm}

Trabajo fin de máster\\
\vspace{0.32cm}

\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,1.00}{One}\\
\vspace{0.32cm}

\Fontvi{
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  Presentado por: & Xan \\
    \hline
 Fecha: & Marzo de 2.016 \\  
  \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}


}


\frame{\Fontvi{\tableofcontents}}

\section{Introducción}
\frame
{
Aquí estará el planteamiento del problema.
}
\subsection{Problema}
\frame
{
\frametitle{This is the second slide}
\framesubtitle{A bit more information about this}
}

\subsection{Justificación}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Objetivos}
\frame
{
}

\section{Marco Teórico}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Modelo Van Hiele}
\frame
{
}

\frame
{
}

\subsection{Modelo Vinner}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Modelo Duval}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Visualización y representación}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Obstáculos a la enseñanza efectiva}
\frame
{
}

\section{Propuesta de Intervención}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Actividad 1}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Actividad 2}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Actividad 3}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Actividad 4}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Actividad 5}
\frame
{
}

\section{Conclusiones}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Conclusiones-Discusión}
\frame
{
}

\subsection{Limitaciones y prospectiva}
\frame
{
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those spaces are left for title and authors. Fill in the `\title{}` and `\author{}` and you will see.

If you do want to ignore those information, the definition is originally in `beamerouterthemesidebar.sty` line 129-155

> ```
>   \defbeamertemplate*{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}{sidebar theme}
>   {
>     \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
>     \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
>     {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
>       \vskip1.5em%
>       \hskip3pt%
>       \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
>       \insertshorttitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
>       \vskip1.25em%
>     }%
>     {%
>       \hskip3pt%
>       \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
>       \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
>       \insertshortauthor[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
>       \vskip1.25em%
>     }%
>     \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
>     \vfill
>     \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
>     \else%
>       \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
>       \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
>       \vskip2pt%
>     \fi%
>   }%
> ```

by removing the two subgroups, one gets

[image]

```
\defbeamertemplate*{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}{sidebar theme revised}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
```

Comment: thank you, but I prefer this other answer for being simplier and easier to understand. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289745/increasing-the-size-of-the-navigation-sidebar-text-in-beamer-berkeley-theme/290299#290299